# Articulation between X and Y

Tags: word-usage

I've just come across a strange use of "**articulation**", specifically: "*the articulation between the public and the private sphere*".

I thought for sure this must be an error by a non-native speaker; but in searching for the phrase "articulation between public" to confirm, I get a high number of results from high-quality sources.

Is this more common than I thought? Does it have any nuanced meaning in this context beyond the way two organized entities cooperate and interact?

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of a word that has multiple meanings, and the context you have described is one usage. It does have a slightly more nuanced meaning in that *the articulation* refers not just to how the two bodies interact but also the specific way they communicate with each other.

Comment: Do you have a reference to support your answer?

Answer (score -1):

From the Latin *artus* (joint) we get 'article' (small attached part) and 'articulate' (move at a joint).

We articulate our jaws to form words clearly, but we are also articulate if we arrange our words so that they convey meaning clearly.

Comment: That really doesn't have anything to do with the question, which is about a specific, uncommon use of the word.

Comment: I thought the use was about cooperation (via communication) between two parts of society, which is what my final clause addressed.